# Tkinter - How to pass a variable using modules?

Tags: python, class, object, tkinter

I need to take a value from user and then pass this value into function to get a string with this values. My code in first file looks like below (of course it is simplified version):

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import myfunction  # this is my module that has another function

class Interface(ttk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, container):
        super().__init__(container)

        self.user_price_minimum = tk.StringVar()

        minimum_price = ttk.Label(self, text="Minimum price is: ")
        minimum_price.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)
        minimum_price_entry = ttk.Entry(self, width=15, textvariable = self.user_price_minimum)
        minimum_price_entry.grid(row=0, column=1)
        minimum_price_entry.focus()

        #############
        button = ttk.Button(self, text="Use price")

        button.grid(column=0, rows=2, columnspan=2, padx=5, pady=5)

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("450x250")
root.title("Looking for a flat")
root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

frame = Interface(root)
frame.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

My another python file that calls `myfunction.py` should be able to take this `minimum_price` from user and add this into string. Code looks like below:

```
def minimum_price(self):
    price_min = self.user_price_minimum.get()
    price_min = int(price_min)

    print(f'Minimum price is: {price_min}')
```

So I am not sure how I could use `minimum_price` values from user into this function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest is to do this:

```py
button = ttk.Button(self, text="Use price", command=lambda: myfunction.minimum_price(self))
```

However you could also define it as a method in the class itself:

```py
class Interface(ttk.Frame):
    
    def __init__(self, container):
        super().__init__(container)
    
        self.user_price_minimum = tk.StringVar()
            
        minimum_price = ttk.Label(self, text="Minimum price is: ")
        minimum_price.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)
        minimum_price_entry = ttk.Entry(self, width=15, textvariable = self.user_price_minimum)
        minimum_price_entry.grid(row=0, column=1)
        minimum_price_entry.focus()
        
        #############
        button = ttk.Button(self, text="Use price", command=self.print_price)
        button.grid(column=0, rows=2, columnspan=2, padx=5, pady=5)  
        
    def print_price(self):
        price = self.user_price_minimum.get()
        print(f'Minimum price: {price}')
```

My personal preference (when using another file in such a case like this one (tho I would probably prefer to define this as above)) would be if:

```py
# in the other file
def minimum_price(value):
    print(f'Minimum price: {value}')

# inside the class
button = ttk.Button(self, text="Use price", command=lambda: myfunction.minimum_price(self.user_price_minimum.get()))
```

Also in this case you don't necessarily need the `StringVar`, you could also simply get the value by using:

```py
# assignment
self.minimum_price_entry = ttk.Entry(self, width=15)

# get value (probably in some function call, basically the same way as with the `StringVar` except less code)
self.minimum_price_entry.get()
```

Comment: Thanks mate! It works with lambda. And thanks for second option but I would like to keep my function in another python file

Comment: @Tmiskiewicz btw in the current function you don't need to convert the value to `int`, you are only printing it (obvs for calculations if you later add such, you may need the integer value (in which case since it would be user input, you will probably need to add some `try/except` or `if statements` to check for or catch an error if the value cannot be converted to integer))

Comment: `command=print_price` should be `command=self.print_price`.